# Which Linux distribution is the latest openVAS available on?

Tags: debian, alpine-linux, vulnerability

It has been removed from the latest Alpine and their solution is to downgrade your system from 3.11 to 3.10.

It's no longer available on Debian, their solution is to build it from source.

Is there any Linux distribution whose repositories include the latest openVAS?

Comment: Alpine 3.14 has an up to date version according to pkgs.org via the Alpine Community x86_64 repository.. The version on 3.11 is already pretty significantly out of date.
Also Centos 8 via the 3rd Party Atomic Repo has up-to-date openVAS.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of OpenVAS package in Alpine. v3.11 was released in 2019, and the packages are not upgraded for other reasons than security upgrade and fixes.
So for the latest release you can use the edge version (which is rolling and has the last update, but of course is not "stable"), or the latest stable release, v3.14 at the moment. You can check the releases here https://alpinelinux.org/releases/

Answer (score 1):

The latest stable release of Alpine (v3.14) has OpenVAS 21.4.x :   https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.14/community/x86_64/openvas

As you might be aware, OpenVAS is composed by several packages. Some of these are not exactly at the very same version (e.g. latest release of gvm-tools is 21.6.1 at the time of writing).

So when you ask for the "latest release", we should go ahead and ask you "to which specific package are you referring to, in the OpenVAS suite?".

But to avoid to be picky, if you want the latest OpenVAS releases for the suite, they are all available in edge[*]:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/openvas

**Please be aware that edge is the latest release of Alpine that is not considered stable, is rolling and continuously updated.**

[*] See: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge for more information about Edge

Hope it helps.

.: Francesco